# Is it fine to put 4 wood blocks around the crimson/corruption

Tags: terraria

I am just about to kill the wall of flesh and i dont want the crimson/corruption to spread over my base or
jungle i am thinking that i can just put 4 wood blocks around to stop the corruption/crimson

Answer (score 2):

Biomes can only spread within three tiles, so any 4-tile gap of resistant material will prevent spread. Wood is one such material. So is air, which is a lot faster and cheaper (though an air-only gap can be bridged by plant growth in some arrangements).

Bear in mind that large amounts of Corruption/Crimson and Hallow will generate upon entering hardmode, so trying to enclose the spawned biome beforehand is pointless. Smashing altars will also cause new evil to spawn. Enclosing the areas you want to protect (spawn, jungle) is a better strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will stop the corruption/crimson but bear in mind the hallow will spawn in hardmode, so this seems kind of pointless until hardmode. My recommendation is defeat the wall of flesh, see where the corruption/crimson/hallow is, and then put 4 blocks of wood/air to stop them spreading further.